# VB.NET/Access - Calculate how many data entries/total attendance for each student

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a table with the follow fields.  StudentID, LastName, FirstName, TrainDate.  I have windows form that I use to input the date of attendance in the TrainDate field.  The TrainDate field is short text.  My goal is to count how many TrainDate entries each person has and display it in a datagridview.

This is the query I am working on but I get the following error:  "Date type mismatch in criteria expression"

```
Access.ExecQuery("SELECT FirstName AS [FIRST NAME], LastName AS [LAST NAME],
                             SUM(TrainDate) AS [TOTAL CLASSES]
                      FROM ACJATTENDANCE
                      GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, TrainDate;")

    ' REPORT & ABORT ON ERRORS
    If NoErrors(True) = False Then End

    ' FILL DATAGRID
    dgvAttend.DataSource = Access.DBDT
```

Can someone help me figure out the reason for the error?  I have used this query to calculate wins and losses in another part of the program successfully.  I'm not sure but I think this has something to do with TrainDate.

Comment: I suspect it's the clause `SUM(TrainDate)`, try `COUNT(TrainDate)`. I think Access is having issue SUMMING dates when I think you want to do a Count of them

Answer (score 1):

You are counting attendances so you probably want to use the COUNT function instead of SUM
Don't forget to remove TrainDate from GROUP BY selection, otherwise you will not get the result you want.

```
SELECT FirstName AS [FIRST NAME], LastName AS [LAST NAME],
COUNT(TrainDate) AS [TOTAL CLASSES]
FROM ACJATTENDANCE
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName ;
```

Comment: That gives me the result I am looking for as far as counting the total class for each student.

I wanted to add TrainDate AS [Most Resent Training Day] how could I do that without messing up the total class count?

Comment: Yoou can add MAX(TrainDate) to the SELECT to get the most recent date

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my date field in my database table was set to short text instead of Date\Time.